# Sticky navigation - logo moves down page on mobile version when it shouldn't

Tags: css, wordpress

I am having an issue with the mobile version of a site. I have managed to get the navigation to stay at the top of the page, but the logo moves down as the user scrolls.

I have tried various suggestions I have found on here and other sites including:

```
#masthead .site-header  {
position: relative !important; }

#sticky_navigation {
position: relative;
top: 0; 
}
```

These are all within a media query for mobiles.

I am pretty new to code, so I'm sure it's probably a rookie error!

This is a link to the site. http://coppercatphotography.co.uk/demo/wordpress/

Thank you!

Comment: try changing your `position:relative` to `position:fixed`

Comment: You could change the position:fixed; rule on line 155 to position:absolute; but that only stops the logo from moving down the page as you scroll in mobile view, it doesn't stop the nav from scrolling with the page, not sure if you want a sticky nav on mobile view as well as other views?
Also, I can't see any element with an ID of masthead in that demo site, so that !important ruling won't have any affect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason that your logo is moving down with the page is because your declaration `.container_16 .grid_5` has `position: fixed`. You'll need to remove this or overwrite it. You could do:

```
#sticky_navigation .container_16 .grid_5 {
    position: absolute;
}
```

That should overwrite it and resolve your issue. (I have used absolute instead of relative as relative seems to affect other elements on your page.)

Comment: Thank you! Absolute worked a treat. I knew it would be something relative simple

Comment: Perfect. Glad I could help! :)